# How to load and Mathml formula into Libreoffice

Tags: mathml, libreoffice

I have a MATHML formula (generated by, i.e., http://www.mathtoweb.com/cgi-bin/mathtoweb_online.pl). I want to paste it into Libreoffice. How could I do that?

Or even better, I want to convert it to an odf-formula standard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try to use the "import formula" functionality?

Just insert a new formula object:

[image: insert formula]

And you have two methods to import. The first one, import the MathML as XML:

[image: import formula]

For import, paste the MathML code into a text file and save it using the file name extension `.mml`. This way, LO Math should recognize the MathML content and convert it into its internal format.

The second method, "Import MathML from Clipboard" (supported in LO 5.2):
[image: import formula]

Comment: for import_formula you need to add a file. Is there any way of pasting directly the formula?

Comment: great but does not import the mml file... I'll send bug report

Comment: Do I need special filename or something, as it does nothing.

Comment: The file name extension should be `.mml`. It seems that the extension matters, sine LO doesn't import anything from a  `.xml` with the same content.

Comment: @Bogdan: Importing MathML from Clipboard works for me with Linux Mint 19.2, LO 6.0.7.3.

Comment: @tohuwawohu Glad to hear that. Could you please tell me how. I have Libre Office 6.2 and I don't have the menu item in the Tools menu and CTRL+V does past the MATH ML text but in the source form. i.e. is not rendered/interpreted

Comment: @Bogdan: I've checked 6.2.7.1, and the menu entries are there. Maybe you didn't proceed as i've explained, and thus you've hit the Tools Menu of LO Writer. That's the wrong place. You'll need to proceed how i've explained - insert a Formula Object, so LO Math appears. In the Tools Menu of LO Math, the entries are there as explained.

Comment: @tohuwawohu You are right, I did not pay attention. I did not expect contextual menus. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Latest Libreoffice v 5.1 can import mathml formulas directly from clipboard. Currently 5.1 is beta, but you may download beta builds [here](http://www.libreoffice.org/download/pre-releases/)

The screenshot is in Russian (my beta supports only russian lang, unfortunately), but it's oblious how to do it (Tools -> Import MathML from clipboard)
[image: MAthml import]